# limit of the sequence $(n+1)^\alpha - n^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $u_n$ be defined as : $u_n = (n+1)^{\alpha} - n^\alpha$.
>   Now I would like to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$ (this limit depends on the choice of $\alpha$).

Here is what I found so far :

If $\alpha \in [0,1[$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$. If $\alpha = 1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 1$. If $\alpha \geq 2$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = +\infty$.

Now for $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha \geq 2$ it's really easy to get the result. For $\alpha \in [0,1)$ I found it hard and here is what I do :

we use the mean value theorem to say that : 
$$\mid (n+1)^\alpha - n^\alpha \mid \leq \alpha n^{\alpha-1} \to 0$$
And we get the desired result. Now my question is :

1- Is it possible to get the limit when $\alpha\in [0,1)$ with an other technique (without using the mean value theorem) ?

2- How to get the limit when $\alpha \in (1, 2)$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: $f(x) =x^a$ then $f'=ax^{a-1}$

Comment: The $\alpha n^{1-\alpha}$ above should be $\alpha n^{\alpha-1}$

Comment: What do you mean by $[0, 1[$ ?

Comment: May mean $[0,1)$

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for noticing this. It shoud be correct now

Comment: @dmtri Thank you for catching the mistake. And yes it mean $[0,1)$.

Comment: Why not let $x=1/n$ and use L'Hopital on $(1+x)^a-1\over x^a$ as $x\to0^+$? It seems to me you get $+\infty$ for the limit as soon as $a\gt1$.

Comment: You may try also Bernoulli inequality.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276667/for-alpha-in-0-frac32-define-x-n-n1-alpha-n-alpha-then?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that
$$\alpha n^{\alpha-1} \leq u_n\leq \alpha(n+1)^{\alpha-1}.$$
Hence by the Sandwich theorem,
$$\lim \alpha n^{\alpha-1}\leq\lim u_n\leq\lim\alpha n^{\alpha-1}$$
since $\lim \alpha n^{\alpha-1}=\lim\alpha (n+1)^{\alpha-1}$. It remains to find $\lim\alpha n^{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: How did you obtain that estimate? Note that OP asked for a  technique “without using the mean value theorem.”

Comment: @MartinR There's no need for MVT. Just note that the derivative of the function is monotonous (by looking at the second derivative) so that we have the desired bound by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha\le 0$ the limit is $0$.
Suppose $\alpha > 0$.

We write: $$u_n=n^{\alpha}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{\alpha}=n^{\alpha}\left(-\frac{\alpha}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})\right)$$
$$=\alpha n^{\alpha-1}+o(n^{\alpha-2})$$
We conclude that:

> If $0<\alpha<1, u_n\longrightarrow 0$
>
> If $\alpha>1, u_n\longrightarrow \infty$
>
> if $\alpha=1$ the limit is 1.